# How do I optionally slow down cucumber (ruby) tests?

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, automated-tests, cucumber

I have tried googling, but had no luck. Maybe I just don't know the terms to search for...

Recently we made some changes to the environment, and now tests that used to run without issue kill the service. We are working to find out why that is happening... but in the meantime, is there a way I could pass a CLI command or something to slow down the tests on demand? (or vice versa, run at full speed on demand) Or maybe build something into a rake task?

I know I could easily add an after hook to sleep between scenarios, but I want to be able to run the tests full blast as well while we are trying to sort out the issue. Adding an after hook would require editing several files every time we wanted to turn the throttling on or off.

**UPDATE:**

decided to try adding this to env.rb and I think it might work, although it feels crude. If you have other suggestions I would love to hear them. This is just a temporary fix though, once we figure out what is up with the environment we do need to go back and add a more elegant way of slowing tests down when needed, perhaps through the http client.

```
After do
  if ENV['SLOW'].eql? 'yes'
    sleep(3)
    @logger.info '******* Waiting 3 seconds before running next scenario *******'
  end
end
```

Comment: why do you need to slowdown em? if you want to find problem area, may be there is a sense to run test files separately?

Comment: What part of the tests are you trying to slow down? Between individual tests / scenarios? Before launching a suite a tests? Making the individual tests themselves take longer...?

Comment: That was the part I wasn't sure about. Our system is built around eventual consistency, so things are not always available instantly. We switched to a Kupernetes container for that environment, and suddenly the tests would bring down the service every time they ran. We have since upped memory and replicas, which seems to have fixed the problem... but we need to investigate the load the tests are throwing at the system. I need to learn more about this, as I have never had to think about slowing tests down before.. usually the ask is to speed them up!

Comment: Also, slowing the tests down by adding time between scenarios didn't help much in the end. After adding a few seconds between steps on the ones that were still failing, I was still only able to cut the remaining number of failing scenarios in half... but those still borked the system causing 503's that didn't recover for certain endpoints.